# CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Geant4/geant4_10_02-build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, geant4

this is my first time using this and very new in C++. I'm trying to install *Geant4* developed by CERN...but i think the main problem that I'm having here is CMake ...does anyone know how i can fix this? I have already tried to fix this by searching on the internet this error message but most of the solutions are for Linux or Mac and I'm using Windows. Honestly I just don't understand where the problem might be.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Two things 1. Trust that CMake is telling you the truth about the folder not containing the required `CMakeLists.txt` file. 2. c:/Program Files is a very bad place to have your source code especially code that contains a `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Have you tried tried the official [installation guide](https://geant4-userdoc.web.cern.ch/geant4-userdoc/UsersGuides/InstallationGuide/html/installguide.html#on-windows-platforms)?

Comment: yeah, Im very new into C++, thanks I will keep on reading

Comment: @drescherjm i didnt know that...i will move the source code

Comment: I recommend something like c:\projects or c:\programming

Comment: ***Im very new into C++*** this really is not that much about `c++` its more  about how to use `CMake` and partially about your familiarity with the command line and how your OS works.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks!!